# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null Битрикс

Tags: jquery, битрикс

хоть и в интернете есть много вопросов с ответами, но со своей частью не справился.

Изначально дизайн был совсем другой, когда все убрал и сделал по своему появилась такая ошибка

```
VM3601 page_05c242cadfc54ab368ff3550ca311ecc_v1.js:434 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at SmartFilter.BX.Iblock.SmartFilter.SmartFilter.setMinFilteredValue (VM3601 page_05c242cadfc54ab368ff3550ca311ecc_v1.js:434)
    at SmartFilter.BX.Iblock.SmartFilter.SmartFilter.init (VM3601 page_05c242cadfc54ab368ff3550ca311ecc_v1.js:412)
    at new SmartFilter (VM3601 page_05c242cadfc54ab368ff3550ca311ecc_v1.js:369)
    at (index):3277
    at ue (VM3568 core.min.js:1)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (VM3568 core.min.js:1)
```

ругается на этот код

```
SmartFilter.prototype.setMinFilteredValue = function (fltMinPrice) {
    this.fltMinPrice = parseFloat(fltMinPrice);
    if(this.fltMinPrice >= this.minPrice) {
        var priceDiff = this.fltMinPrice - this.minPrice;
        this.fltMinPercent = (priceDiff*100)/this.priceDiff;

        if(this.leftPercent > this.fltMinPercent)
            this.colorAvailableActive.style.left = this.leftPercent + "%";
        else
            this.colorAvailableActive.style.left = this.fltMinPercent + "%";

        this.colorAvailableInactive.style.left = this.fltMinPercent + "%";
    } else {
        this.colorAvailableActive.style.left = "0%";
        this.colorAvailableInactive.style.left = "0%";
    }
};
```

Совсем не понятно где че убирать, из за этого остальной js код не работает

Answer (score 0):

Вряд ли тебе это будет полезно, но, возможно, кто-то еще столкнется с этой проблемой. Ошибка значит, что компонент не может найти дефолтных контроллеров (поскольку менялся дизайн, и фильтр, вероятно, был переверстан с нуля). Можно просто закомментировать этот if-else блок, он влияет только на отображение ползунков в дефолтном компоненте.